# Enable resizing of windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to ENABLE resizing of my windows form, because the option of dragging the window into a bigger or smaller window should be available for the user. I have set my FormBorderStyle = Sizable and tried to set max and MinimumSize like this:

```
    this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1680, 1050);
    this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(995, 765);
```

before the max and minimumsize was set to be 0,0. But it still doesnt work.

I have one form as a shell for 3 user controls that are inserted into the "shell form". Can this be effecting the resizing abillity ?

Comment: Show us the code!

Comment: In particular, it would also help to know whether you have set a `MinimumSize` or `MaximumSize` for your form.

Comment: they are both set to true. But the thing is that im using the form as a shell. and inserting user controls in the form. would that effect the resixing abillity ?

Comment: There is no such thing as `MinimumSize = true` or `MaximumSize = true` as none are `bool` to begin with.

Comment: @Lahib - You need to update your question.  Your answers to our followup questions make no sense.

Comment: i have just updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set my form to be a MDI container. After setting my IsMdiContainer to be false i was avble to resize my form.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you haven't set the MaximumSize and MinimumSize Layout Properties.

Comment: they are both set to true.

Comment: Show us how you set them to `true`

Comment: When you say 'set to true' you mean they both read 0,0 , right?

Comment: im sorry. I thought u wrote Maximizebox and Minimizebox propperty. Im gonna try setting the Max and Minimumsize now.

Comment: If you don't set them and leave them as 0,0 they should allow re-sizing of the form, but if you set them and it works, it could be something else...